# using existing gradle wrapper while importing projects in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, wrapper

I am using android studio for my android projects.I just got a problem when i imported an android studio project.The problem is that gradle is downloading `wrapper 2.4` and i have `2.1.0`. Is there a way to use older version by changing setting. I searched about it but i didn't find solutions specific to the problem.what i got is

[How to set gradle home while importing existing project in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646252/how-to-set-gradle-home-while-importing-existing-project-in-android-studio)

[How to use gradle zip in local system without downloading when using gradle-wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896569/how-to-use-gradle-zip-in-local-system-without-downloading-when-using-gradle-wrap)

In my case, i don't have version 2.4 and want to use existing 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `distributionUrl` values with your currently version `(2.1.0)` and then :

```
./gradlew clean assemble
```

> Remove `.idea` folder and ***all .iml*** files and import the project
>   as new one.

check this answer too:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22366006/4409113

And: [Force Android Studio to download and install gradle 1.10 or 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359831/force-android-studio-to-download-and-install-gradle-1-10-or-1-1)

Comment: i got error "no cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0"